# PHP arrays in HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, html-table

I got 3 PHP arrays which I've put inside a HTML table. The table headers are correctly displayed but the data not. That are the `<td>`'s. The table rows and `<td>`'s are displayed under each other and not in the columns. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
echo '<table border="1"><tr><th><b>Gebruikersnaam</b></th><th>Functie</th><th>E-mailadres</th></tr>';
sort($result);

foreach($result as $key)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>'; 
}

foreach ($result as $key=>$function)
  {
    $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("title"));
    $title = $check[0]['title'][0];
    if(empty($title)) {
    echo '<td>Geen functie</td>';
    } else {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    }
foreach ($result as $key=>$function)
{
    $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("mail"));
    $title = $check[0]['mail'][0];
      echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';  
      echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

And here is an idea what my problem is:

```
| Column 1        |  Column 2      |  Column 3        |
----------------------------------------------------
|   value1        |                |                  |
|---------------------------------------------------
|   value2        |                |                  |
|---------------------------------------------------
|   value3        |                |                  |
|---------------------------------------------------
|   value4 etc    |                |                  |
|---------------------------------------------------
```

All the arrays appear in the first column. I used `<tr> <td>` nothing works.

EDIT
This is the $result variable. (Using the ADLDAP php class).

```
$result = $adldap->group()->members($groepbekijken, $sorted = true);
```

Comment: Could you also list what the content of $result is?

Comment: I updated my post with the $result variable.

Comment: The result of the command var_dump($result), will be welcomed. It will show us what you have stored inside it, because the problem probably lies in there.

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing incorrect html, after every `<td></td>` you also have a `</tr>` closing tag.

```
foreach($result as $key)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Here you only output 1  in every

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$function)
  {
    $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("title"));
    $title = $check[0]['title'][0];
    if(empty($title)) {
    echo '<td>Geen functie</td>';
    } else {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    }
```

Here you or output `<td></td>` OR you output `<tr><td><td></tr>`

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$function)
{
    $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("mail"));
    $title = $check[0]['mail'][0];
      echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';  
      echo '</tr>';
}
```

And here you output `<tr><td></td></tr>`

So, what is the problem then? well, your code is a mess. Sorry, but it really is.

You have a foreach over the same $result three times. why?

Put it into one foreach, makes it more readable:

```
foreach ( $result as $key => $functions )
{
    echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';

        $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("title"));
        $title = $check[0]['title'][0];

        if( empty($title) )
        {
            echo '<td>Geen functie</td>';
        } else
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        $check = $adldap->user()->info($function, array("mail"));
        $title = $check[0]['mail'][0];
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';  
        echo '</tr>';


    echo '</tr>';
}
```

But then again, this is still bad code. Don't mix presentation 'html' and logic 'that $adlap-> thing'.

And please, dont echo stuff out in a function. return it as a string, and then echo it.